# Ways to improve average image filtering speed

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Average image filtering is a very common image pre-processing function, and a short introduction of average filtering can be found [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/mean.htm). In Opencv this is done by [cv::blur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur).

When the size of the average filter increase, the time taken by this processing will increase as well.Common ways of improving the speed of average filtering can be divided into two categories:

- Improve speed in the spatial domain such as [Fast mean ﬁltering technique](http://www.isical.ac.in/~ash/Rakshit-pr-07.pdf)
- Improve speed in the frequency domain using 2D-FFT

So here my question is: what method is often used to improve the speed of average image filtering? If someone has worked on this topic, what is the advantage and dis-advantage of each method? Has someone compared the speed of cv::blur with the improved average image filtering? Thanks.

Comment: FFT is the normal way to go with large kernels - you often need the FFT anyway for subsequent processing so it's no additional overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple average filter, the best option is to use a fast spatial domain optimization, like the one you linked. One other example is [Integral Images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).

The basic idea is that inside the filter box, certain sums are shared between adjacent boxes and don't need to be computed again. The downside is that you need additional memory to store these intermediate values. The advantage is that the complexity is independent of the kernel size (given an N by N image, the complexity is `N * N * constant`).

Using frequency domain techniques is convenient only if you already have the image FFT ready, maybe because it's needed for other kind of processing. Otherwise calculating a 2D FFT is a `N * N * logN * constant` operation, thus outperformed by spatial optimized filtering.